# Which is the best platform to develop an external corporate website - .Net or Sharepoint

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, content-management-system

The website needs to be equipped with a content management system and should provide for social media integration and localization.

What are the pros and cons of each technology platform and when should we opt for sharepoint?

Comment: 1. Internal or external? 2. Why not any other options? Basically: need far more information, therefore please read: http://tinyurl.com/so-hints (as it stands there is no useful answer that can be given in the scope provided here).

Comment: -1: this is really an unspecified question.

Comment: what does 'best' mean: time, dev resources, scalability, security, testability, maintainability, TCO, or other?

Answer (score 8):

This isn't really a question that can be completely answered on an Internet forum. First, it's a given that pretty much any web site *can* be built with either; secondly, building most websites with ASP.NET is also mostly a known quantity - ASP.NET is generally linear, in that developing any feature with it is simple function of developer time.

So the real question is SharePoint - and would you save developer time by leveraging it's power, or spend more time working around it? Only an architect in your organization can fully answer this by:

1. Understanding the requirements;
2. Turning those requirements into questions;
3. Standing up a test instance of SharePoint and spend some proof-of-concept time answering the questions.

SharePoint does indeed offer great capabilities that would take hundreds or thounsands of developer hours to deliver from scratch, and it can be enriched with very small amounts of custom development - *if you can align your requirements to its featureset.* If not, you'll spend 3.5 years and 25,000 developer hours bending it to your needs (not that I have any experience doing such a thing :D)

Comment: Great answer to a very poor question.

Comment: +1 the OP's question is a great example of why so many sharepoint projects go over budget. Nobody spends the requisite time to figure out the requirements and the fit.

Answer (score 1):

If you need content management capabilities SharePoint actually does not require custom code. Moss 2007 and SharePoint Server 2010 come with web content management out of the box. It 'only' requires you to customize the site to give the look and feel your customer wants. Social media definitely requires custom code. A good starting point might be the [community kit](http://cks.codeplex.com/) on codeplex.

If you do not need any of the functions that SharePoint delivers out-of-box - fully or partly - you will be better off with a ASP.NET site. It will mostly likely be faster in development. But as soon as you can leverage some of the SharePoint features it will save you a lot of time. Some of the time saved you will surely spend on weird SharePoint issues and getting to know the product.

Still developing SharePoint is always developing ASP.NET in the end as it is an extension of ASP.NET. So you can do all the stuff such as building web controls, ASCX user controls and web parts in SharePoint as well and at the same time take advantage of the SharePoint deployment mechanism and farm setup that scales well.

Comment: It is very naive to say SharePoint does not require custom code in actual enterprise deployments. The demos give the illusion that it "just works", but the OOB WCM functionality is too generic to be of use to any company with requirements more specific than "make pages and edit them". Inevitably when you deliver OOB WCM to the business users, they will ask for all sorts of customizations.

Comment: I would say that depends on the requirements. I have worked on projects where did not customization to the WCM part and other projects where we spend hundreds of hours on that particular part. As you mentioned yourself it is quite hard to give general advice on this topic. My point is that using available SharePoint infrastructure will save you time.

Answer (score -2):

Simple, For most of companies, the internal site better be using SharePoint, while external site based on ASP.NET.

For internal site: SharePoint basically offers most of the fundamental functionality that most of companies' internal sites require, be it content management, workflow, or permission. It is not a good idea to develop those stuff by yourself, unless your requirements are very special.

For external site: SharePoint is too big and too complex to be an external site, especially for SharePoint 2007. Maybe it is great to seamlessly integrate internal site and external with SharePoint, but considering its lousy compatibility with other browsers as well as clumsy code, it is far better to develop a site by yourself than using SharePoint, then daunted by maintaining lot of codes, writing additional code to improve its compatibility.

Comment: Not true. It's probably not the best for external facing websites but it is nothing 'too'. Plenty of public facing websites have been created with MOSS2007.